# grammar.y error happended when compiled Cobalt

Tags: grammar, cobalt

When compile Cobalt， the following error happend， is there anyone who knows why?
It said the 'ShadowType' is not a class or namespace in grammy.y:3421, I did not know what is used for grammy.y, and try to trace and modify the code, it does not work.

[grammar.y error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytTtr.png)

Comment: Can you add some details about what you've tried ?

Comment: Which branch are you compiling? I don't see occurrences of ShadowType in grammar.y on trunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that C++ version before C++0x does not support ShadowType::kBoxShadow(member in enum type) use at all, you can change the cflags_cc from "-std=gnu++98" to "-std=gnu++0x"in third_party/starboard/linux/shared/gyp_configuration.gypi, and try again.

Comment: Yeah, I try your suggestion, and it works, thanks for kind help.